# Magento: let user complete payment on order in pending payment status

Tags: magento, payment

I have noticed that if an user goes through the checkout process till the paypal form and then ,for whatever reason, exits the page, this order remains in "Pending Payment" status and is no longer visible by the user in his dashboard.

I have found the way to make those orders visible in the user Dashbord here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20121026153121/http://blog.magestore.com/2012/09/11/how-to-show-pending-payment-order-on-front-end/

now i would like to add for those orders a button that let the user complete the payment process.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this ?

thanks!